# Can one define $\langle x,y\rangle$ in $P(C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, logic, axioms

I study at course Foundations of Mathematics the below definitions and lemma:
$\langle x,y\rangle:=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ (from Kuratowski 1921)
$\langle x,y\rangle:=\{\{\{x\},\varnothing\}\{\{y\}\}\}$ (from Norbert Wiener 1914)

> **Lemma :** If $x\in C$ and $y\in C$ then $\langle x,y\rangle\in P(P(C))$. (Lemma is true with Kuratowski definitions and $P(A)$ means power set of $A$)

1. Now is there any proof that explain there is no definition compatible with axioms of set theory and $\langle x,y\rangle\in P(C)$ instead of $P(P(C))$?

It seems answer is "No" for me, but I can't present any proof.
If you know any reference which can help for above question please point it.

## A new approach:

Can we replace the question with below one:

> Prove that there are no formulas $\varphi$ of two free variable, such that for all sets $C$, $\varphi$ describes an injective map from $C\times C$ into $P(C)$.

## An other view to problem:

1. How can I check compatibility of **1.** with axioms of set theory?
2. What informations I will need?

Comment: **Norbert** was a Winner. But his name was Wiener. Also, the definition is not quite correct, you forgot $\varnothing$ in there.

Comment: Also: There is no "fixed enumeration" of the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, so it's not quite clear what are the first six axioms.

Comment: The title of your question says $P(P(C))$, but the body asks about $P(C)$.

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, there is always injective map $C^2 \to \mathcal{P}(C)$.

Comment: However you define the ordered pair, it should have at least two elements; but in $P(\emptyset)$ only one element is available.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari If $\langle x,y\rangle$ must be in $P(\{x,y\})$, this should also hold for $\langle\emptyset,\emptyset\rangle$. The “ambient” $C$ plays no role: the ordered pair can't depend on what set $x$ and $y$ belong to.

Comment: @egreg $\langle\emptyset,\emptyset\rangle = \{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}\}=\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset P(\{\emptyset,\emptyset\})=P(\{\emptyset\})$ and no thing is wrong.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, along the lines of: Prove that there are no formulas $φ$ of two free variable, such that for all sets $C$, $φ$ describes an injective map from $C×C$ into $P(C)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not that well versed in the intricate details of logic.

Comment: It's quite easy to prove that for $C=\{0,1,2\}$ we have $|C\times C|>|\mathcal P(C)|$. So we're done with the proof. But what if you want to say "Well, for finite sets... do something, but for infinite sets, do something else." In this case it is consistent with the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ that there is such $\varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can't do it for very small sets invariably means that you can't do it at all.

First of all, it is important to note that the way we encode the pairs shouldn't depend on the set we are considering at the moment. So $\langle 0,0\rangle$ should be encoded to the same set regardless to use considering it as an ordered pair in $\omega\times\omega$ or in $V_\omega\times V_\omega$.

This means that given an element $a$, $\langle a,a\rangle$ must be in every $A\times A$ whenever $a\in A$. If we want $A\times A\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$, this means that $\langle a,a\rangle\in\bigcap\{\mathcal P(A)\mid a\in A\}=\{\varnothing,\{a\}\}$. Clearly $\varnothing$ cannot encode *all* ordered pairs, so $\langle a,a\rangle=\{a\}$.

This means that $\langle a,b\rangle\in\mathcal P(\{a,b\})$ and that if $a\neq b$ then $\langle a,b\rangle\neq\{a\},\{b\}$. Therefore $\langle a,b\rangle=\{a,b\}$. But therefore $\langle a,b\rangle=\langle b,a\rangle$ even if $a\neq b$. And this is a contradiction to the axioms of the ordered pair.

Therefore there is no consistent definition of an ordered pair such that for every set $A$ we have $A\times A\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$.